# Link two objects in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

I want to construct two different classes point and triangle?

The implementation of the classes is that I will have an array of points, then I will create an array of triangles so each triangle in the array will be linked to three points in the array?

What is the best data structure for the class triangle?

Editing:
Let me explain more:
I have an array of points called Apoints, I want to create a new array of triangle object. I want to assign three points for each triangle. However, for example when I change a point in Apoints, the modification should be implemented as well on all triangles that has this point.

Thank you

Comment: You're asking a very basic question about object oriented programming. Your question shows little in terms of what research you've done beforehand. It screams "my intro to programming teacher is asking us to do this, please do it for me" Could you update your question with a more specific issue you're having with the assignment?

Comment: My interest is that I already have objects of points. I want to have a new triangle object that contains my points without allocating new memory for it. So when I change a point in my array, all triangles that have this point will be changed directly.

Comment: you should read up on pointers for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
class Triangle {
    public:
        Triangle(Point corners[3]) : corners_(corners) {}       
    private:
        Point corners_[3];
};
```

As per your comment, maybe you would want something like this to avoid allocating new memory, but at the same time remain sure that the Triangle only has three Points:

```
class Triangle {
    public:
        Triangle(Point (&corners)[3]) : corners_(corners) {}
    private:
        Point (&corners_)[3];
};
```

A small example could be like this: http://ideone.com/3csNVq

Be careful with ownership and accessing deleted Points though!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, the C++11 way this time:

```
class Triangle {
private:
    std::array<Point,3> m_points;

public:
    Triangle(const std::array<Point,3> & points): m_points(points) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
class Triangle
{
   private:
      Point a;
      Point b;
      Point c;

   public:
      Triangle( Point pa, Point pb, Point pc );
}
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I don't want to have new variables for Triangle class. I want just to use reference to the points so when I have PointA, PointB, PointC and PointD. and TriangleA(PointA, PointB, PointC) and TriangleB(PointB, PointC, PointD). When I change PointB, both Triangles should have the same PointB??

Comment: Instead of Points, use pointers to points, e.g.: `Point* a` OR just store the index into the Point array for each point, e.g.: `int indexA`. Hope that's clear.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go with the simplest solution:

```
class Triangle {
private:
    std::vector<Point*> vertices;
};
```

Comment: @Frecklefoot I didn't see your answer when I click "Answer", otherwise I'll just up vote yours :)

Comment: +1, though you should consider changing `Vector` to `std::vector`.  Once you've done that, the class becomes a good candidate to be a `Polygon`...  of which a Triangle just has 3 points :)

Answer (score 0):

If triangle consists solely of points you don't need to link the elements one by one.

```
struct Point { double c[3]; };

struct Triangle 
{ 
  Point p[3]; 
};

class Triangles
{
public:
  Triangles (Point * point_ptr, size_t const num_points)
    : points(point_ptr), size(num_points)
  { }
  Triangle operator[] (size_t const i)
  {
    size_t p_index = 3*i;
    if (p_index < size)
    {
      return *((Triangle*)points+p_index);
    }
  }
private:
  Point * points;
  size_t size;
};
```

Untested but that's the way you could be doing it.